# How to customize Menu bar in VS2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to rearrange my menu bar in VS2010 so that the external plugins can be pushed into other menu(existing one such as Tools or a new one).

I have referred the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx but without any suggestion regarding this issue.

For example,

```
File | ... | Tools | ReSharper | Windows | Help
```

I need to make it look like the following:

```
File | ... | Tools |  Windows | Help
              -ReSharper
              -Other Plugins
              -Default VS menus
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can come up with is to recreate the Resharper, etc. menus by hand within the tools menu. On the Tools|Customize screen, go to commands, select the "Menu bar" radio, then select Tools from the drop down of menus. From here, add a Menu for Resharper, etc. Now select the "Tools | Resharper" menu and had commands and menus as desired. When done, remove the Resharper menu at the top level.
This is far from ideal, and will likely take you a few minutes of clicking. I'd love to know if there is a better way!